# What are the variables needed for describing Friction, Elasticity, magnetism interactions in a UI

Tags: interaction-design, animation, gestures, microinteractions

Preparing specs for developers of 'pull to refresh' and flick gestures. I'm trying to figure out how to spec these out. Compared to defining normal animations like movement with time and distance this is more complex.

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to talk to the devs and see exactly what they need from you so they can do their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about something which is available in jQuery, which they call "Easings" https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

In this website the movement is communicated using a diagram which animates the movement when clicked. There are variations which include things like bounce and elasticity.

Basically the variable you are missing is the *rate of acceleration*, which can vary throughout the animation, e.g. start slow, speed up, then quickly slowing down, before bouncing, etc.

Comment: thanks but this is not the answer. already know what easings are. what i'm looking for is more like physics characteristics, which can be felt by interacting with it. example in the physical world would be how a squeezing a rubber ball might feel like compared to squeezing a inflated ball